# What is the coimage of a ring homomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

Is there a general way to find the coimage of a ring homomorphism? For example, for the canonical injection $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$, the image is $\mathbb{Z}$ but the coimage is $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Image and coimage are defined relative to a class of monomorphisms resp. epimorphisms. Which ones are you choosing? For the regular image / coimage your statement can't be correct; in that case a morphism $f : c \to d$ should admit a factorization $c \to \text{coim}(f) \to \text{im}(f) \to d$, which is incompatible with what you wrote.

Comment: The image (w.r.t. all monomorphisms) and the regular coimage of a homomorphism of rings always agrees with the set-theoretic image. What might behave in an unusual way is the regular image or the coimage (wr.t. all epimorphisms). Which one of these do you care about?

Comment: I was abusing notation a little bit; as you pointed out, for a morphism $f:c\rightarrow d$, the image is a monomorphism $i\rightarrow d$ and the coimage is an epimorphism $c\rightarrow j$. By "image" and "coimage", I meant $i$ and $j$, respectively. The example I gave about $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$ comes from the fact that a morphism is a monomorphism if and only if it is its own image, and it is an epimorphism if and only if it is its own coimage.

Comment: By "regular" image and coimage, do you mean image and coimage which are regular rings?

Comment: No, I mean image and coimage with respect to regular monomorphisms resp. epimorphisms (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism). The benefit of this definition is that the regular image and regular coimage can be computed using suitable limits and colimits provided that they exist.

Comment: No, I meant just coimage, without any (regularity) condition (as I understand from the link, a coimage which is not necessarily a binary equalizer). I just learned from Wikipedia that even the question of determining whether a morphism of rings is an epimorphism is not so trivial (the case for finitely generated morphism was treated in EGA).

Comment: Yes, the coimage with no qualifiers seems pretty difficult to compute in general. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like for a discussion of epimorphisms in $\text{CRing}$.