# Images and Coimages as Subobjects

Tags: category-theory

Some definitions:

1. Let $C$ be a category and $f: A \rightarrow {B}$ a map.
   A subobject $l: Y \rightarrow {B}$ of $B$ is called IMAGE of $f$ if it fulfills the following:

i) There is a map $g: A \rightarrow {Y}$ such that $l \circ {g} = f$.

ii) If for subobject $l ': Y' \rightarrow {B}$ of $B$ there exists $g ': A \rightarrow {Y'}$ with $l '\circ {g'} = f$, then there is a single map $h: Y \rightarrow {Y '}$ such that $l' \circ {h} = l$.

2. If in $l \circ {g} = f$, $g$ is an epimorphism then the image will be called EPIMORPHIC IMAGE of $f$.
3. By applying duality we obtain the definition of COIMAGEN.

Example 1. The Mod-R category is a category with epimorphic images. Indeed, we consider the homomorphism of R-modules $f: M \rightarrow {N}$
and we know that $Im(f): = \left \{{f (m): m \in M} \right \}$ is a submodule of $N$. The inclusion $l: Im (f) \rightarrow {N}$ is a subobject of $N$ and will be our epimorphic image. Similarly, the category of rings is a category with epimorphic images.

Example 2. The Mod-R category is a category with MONOMORPHIC co-images. Indeed, we consider the homomorphism of R-modules $f: M \rightarrow {N}$ and the quotient object $l: M \rightarrow {M/Ker (f)}$. $L$ is proved to be a monomorphic coimage.

My question is: Does the category of rings have monomorphic co-images?

Comment: What is the definition of a subobject? See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/434952.